# Dialogflow integration with Viber doesn't work with Rich Media type of message

Tags: dialogflow-es

I tried to use a custom payload to send the Carousel to the Viber client from my NODEJS fulfillment. It gives no response.  Here is my code:

```
payload = new Payload(agent.VIBER,  {

   "type":"rich_media",
   "rich_media":{
      "Type":"rich_media",
      "ButtonsGroupColumns":6,
      "ButtonsGroupRows":7,
      "BgColor":"#FFFFFF",
      "Buttons":[
         {
            "Columns":6,
            "Rows":3,
            "ActionType":"open-url",
            "ActionBody":"https://www.google.com",
            "Image":"http://html-test:8080/myweb/guy/assets/imageRMsmall2.png"
         },
         {
            "Columns":6,
            "Rows":2,
            "Text":"<font color=#323232><b>Headphones with Microphone, On-ear Wired earphones</b></font><font color=#777777><br>Sound Intone </font><font color=#6fc133>$17.99</font>",
            "ActionType":"open-url",
            "ActionBody":"https://www.google.com",
            "TextSize":"medium",
            "TextVAlign":"middle",
            "TextHAlign":"left"
         },
         {
            "Columns":6,
            "Rows":1,
            "ActionType":"reply",
            "ActionBody":"https://www.google.com",
            "Text":"<font color=#ffffff>Buy</font>",
            "TextSize":"large",
            "TextVAlign":"middle",
            "TextHAlign":"middle",
            "Image":"https://s14.postimg.org/4mmt4rw1t/Button.png"
         },
         {
            "Columns":6,
            "Rows":1,
            "ActionType":"reply",
            "ActionBody":"https://www.google.com",
            "Text":"<font color=#8367db>MORE DETAILS</font>",
            "TextSize":"small",
            "TextVAlign":"middle",
            "TextHAlign":"middle"
         }
      ]
      }
      }, { sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: false }
    );
agent.add(payload);
```

The only workaround  I found is to use a direct API call to Viber Messaging API from my Fulfillment. It explained well here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/messaging-api-viber

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a limitation of the Dialogflow at this moment. Just use workaround: a direct API call to Viber Messaging API from my Fulfillment. It explained well here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/messaging-api-viber